# setPixel leaving a black border around bitmap, how to avoid?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to alter the colour of certain pixels in a bitmap image. When I alter the colour of pixels in an array of a bitmap image from my drawable folder, it leaves a black border around the different colours which is not desired. How can I do this without the black border?

INITIAL BITMAP:
[image: https://imgur.com/a/JZTSbXe]

I have tried the method below and it leaves the black border:

```
bitmap = bitmap_.copy(bitmap_.getConfig(), true);
    int[] pixels = new int[bitmap.getHeight() * bitmap.getWidth()];
    bitmap.getPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    for(int i = 0; i < pixels.length; i++) {
        if(pixels[i] == Color.rgb(120, 120, 120)) {
            pixels[i] = Color.RED;
        } else
        if(pixels[i] == Color.rgb(90, 90, 90)) {
            pixels[i] = Color.GREEN;
        } else
        if(pixels[i] == Color.rgb(60, 60, 60)) {
            pixels[i] = Color.RED;
        } else
        if(pixels[i] == Color.rgb(30, 30, 30)) {
            pixels[i] = Color.GREEN;
        } else
        if(pixels[i] == Color.rgb(0, 0, 0)) {
            pixels[i] = Color.RED;
        } else {
            pixels[i] = Color.YELLOW;  // Should never fire
        }
    }
    bitmap.setPixels(pixels, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
```

There should be no yellow pixels in the output as the image only consists of pixels with 0,0,0 or multiples of 30 up to 120. It shouldn't be anti-aliasing when I save it. However as you can see there is yellow pixels. Or if I don't recolour them, they go black.

With no recolour:
 [image: black border]

Recolouring the black as yellow:
[image]

Comment: can you share the screenshot?

Comment: added now, didn't add correctly initially

Comment: How can you be sure that there is no anti-aliasing?

Comment: Debug the program, print the pixel when it doesn't match the conditions. Sounds like there's a reasonable chance that your assumption is wrong.

Comment: it only outputs an integer, no idea how that relates to the pixel colour. however it is not anti-aliasing when it saves, it seems as if the android system is doing it when it loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Placing the bitmaps into drawable-nodpi folder prevents Android from scaling them up at runtime, which was causing anti-aliasing.